# Implementar recaptcha em um app Ionic

Tags: ionic, framework, app, recaptcha, captcha

Tentei utilizar todos os plugins que encontrei de verificação (captcha) dentro do meu aplicativo. Estou usando o framework Ionic. Gostaria de saber se há um plugin que funcione dentro do código html nesse caso.

Alguns dos quais eu tentei implementar utilizavam a tag  e recebi um erro do console alertando que essa tag não existia, mesmo incluindo tudo que a documentação pedia.

Answer (score 2):

Assumindo que esta seja sua pergunta:

> Gostaria de saber se há um plugin que funcione dentro do código html nesse caso.

Use o plugin de componente [ng-recaptcha](https://github.com/DethAriel/ng-recaptcha) para Angular 2+. Funciona perfeitamente no Ionic.

Adicione o módulo ao seu arquivo `app.module.ts` (ou similar):

```
import { RecaptchaModule } from 'ng-recaptcha';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MyApp } from './app.component.ts';

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [MyApp],
  declarations: [MyApp],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RecaptchaModule.forRoot(), //importante
  ],
})
export class MyAppModule { }
```

E então, no seus templates html, declare da seguinte maneira:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<re-captcha (onResolve)="resolved($event)" siteKey="CHAVE_DO_SEU_SITE"></re-captcha>',
}) 
export class MyApp {
  onResolve(captcha : string) {
    console.log(`Token captcha ${captcha}:`);
  }
}
```

Onde *CHAVE_DO_SEU_SITE* é obtida através do cadastro no [site da Google reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin).

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/130838)

Comment: @Stormwind adicionei a devida implementação para auxiliar o solicitante.

Comment: Boa resposta, parece muito mais completa =)